# Puppy barks at other dogs

Tags: dogs, vocalizations

We have a 13 weeks old hybrid puppy. It's a mix between a black Labrador, Golden retriever and Australian Shepard.

She is very happy to meet other dogs and gets along with most of them. The problem is that she barks a lot and constantly in different situations. Mostly when...

1. ... approaching the dog
2. ... the other dog ignores her
3. ... the other dog frightened her

The problem is that we don't know how to react to this behaviour. We are not sure whether to try to get here focus on us, scold or ignore her.

What do you think is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Dogs bark for a lot of reasons.For example, she may bark at other dogs or people to get their attention. If it's low pitched, short woofs, with lots of breaks, she's just being playful.  But if the bark is loud, high pitched along with growling, she might be angry, or trying to frighten the fellow dogs/people.

I think it's pretty normal for dogs to bark when meeting new people and other dogs. But if you want to stop her from doing so, you can scold her, so she knows it's a behavior that makes you angry and is not to be continued.